# minpack fortran .dll for use in c#

Tags: c#, gcc, dll, fortran, gnu

I am trying to include minpack, which is written in FORTRAN and is used for least square solutions to underdetermined maths problems, in my c# windows form solution.

I have read that it is possible to compile the minpack fortran subroutines, of which there are 7 (all in separate files) into a .dll, which I can then add as a reference to my c# program in visual studio 2012.

I have been attempting to do this now for 2 days with not much luck.  I have downloaded GCC GNU to compile the fortran files.  My steps so far are:

1) compile fortran files to Common Object File Format (COFF *.o) files using the syntax "gcc -c filename1.f" in the mingw64env command prompt for all 7 files

2) I have then compiled these files together into a shared executable using the syntax "gcc -shared -o mindpack.dll filename1.o filename2.o filename3.o..."

this outputs a .dll file with no reported errors.

3) But when I try to add it as a reference to my windows forms project (c#) I get the error message "A reference to '*.dll' could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

4) one of the suggestions to fix this was to find the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\TlbImp.exe and execute it with the syntax "TlbImp.exe minpack.dll" but this gives the error "TlbImp : error T10000 : The input file 'C:\mingw64\minpack.dll' is not a valid type library.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as I've only started learning c# and some of the solutions online are over my head with things like header files and DEF files, im not sure if these are even relevant.

If someone could lay out a solution to converting a collection of fortran subroutines into a single .dll file that can be called from c#, preferably using GCC GNU (or some other free software), it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmanaged dll can't be added as a reference to a C# application. GCC can not easily link COM object for you.

If the dll exports a number of global functions, then you should be able to use Platfrom Invoke (DllImport attribute) to call them from C#

Please look at this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tanmayit08/unmanaged-cpp-dll-call-from-managed-C-Sharp-application/) or any other from Google search.

Comment: there is only one global function, the rest of them are only called from within the global function.  does this change your advice at all or is this still the way to proceed?

Comment: No difference between one global function or number of them. This only means, that you must call single function through P/Invoke, and thus simplifies things.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is somewhat orthogonal to the question as it avoids Fortran entirely, but given the prevalence of the question in search results on C# and MINPACK, it is worth mentioning that an [open source C/C++ port of MINPACK](https://github.com/devernay/cminpack) is available, which may simplify the process of making something callable from .NET.

To use this particular library,

1. download a [release version of the source code](https://github.com/devernay/cminpack/releases), the most recent at the time of writing being 1.6.3.
2. Open the Visual C++ solution, `cminpack.sln`, contained within, and build it to obtain the library, `cminpack_dll.dll`.
3. Add `cminpack_dll.dll` to your .NET solution and make sure that it is copied to the output directory when building.
4. At this point, the library can be called using [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

The example below shows how to fit a quadratic function to a given collection of data points:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Define some test data by 5i + 3i^2. The plan is to let cminpack figure out
        // the values 5 and 3.
        var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
            .Select(i => 5 * i + 3 * Math.Pow(i, 2))
            .ToList();

        CminpackFuncMn residuals = (p, m, n, x, fvec, iflag) =>
        {
            unsafe
            {
                // Update fvec with the values of the residuals x[0]*i + x[1]*i^2 - data[i].
                var fvecPtr = (double*)fvec;
                var xPtr = (double*)x;
                for (var i = 0; i < m; i++)
                    *(fvecPtr + i) = *xPtr * i + *(xPtr + 1) * Math.Pow(i, 2) - data[i];
            }
            return 0;
        };

        // Define an initial (bad) guess for the value of the parameters x.
        double[] parameters = { 2d, 2d };
        var numParameters = parameters.Length;
        var numResiduals = data.Count;
        var lwa = numResiduals * numParameters + 5 * numParameters + numResiduals;

        // Call cminpack
        var info = lmdif1(
            fcn: residuals,
            p: IntPtr.Zero,
            m: numResiduals,
            n: numParameters,
            x: parameters,
            fvec: new double[numResiduals],
            tol: 0.00001,
            iwa: new int[numParameters],
            wa: new double[lwa],
            lwa: lwa);

        // parameters now contains { 5, 3 }.
        Console.WriteLine($"Return value: {info}, x: {string.Join(", ", parameters)}");
    }

    [DllImport("cminpack_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int lmdif1(CminpackFuncMn fcn, IntPtr p, int m, int n, double[] x,
        double[] fvec, double tol, int[] iwa, double[] wa, int lwa);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int CminpackFuncMn(IntPtr p, int m, int n, IntPtr x, IntPtr fvec, int iflag);
}
```

Here, the signatures of `lmdif1` and `CminpackFuncMn` can be deduced through inspection of the [relevant header file](https://github.com/devernay/cminpack/blob/master/minpack.h) in cminpack.